# Auto adjust UITableView's header

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, constraints, autolayout

I have static tableview with some cells that I want to be anchored to the bottom of the screen. I've added an UIImageView as the tableview's header, I want this UIImageView to be adjustable in height so that on 3.5 inch screens the tableview header is smaller than on 4 inch screen (and prevents scrolling for those on the smaller screens).

I can't figure out how to achieve this in interface builder using constraints or autolayout (I'd prefer not to drop into code if possible), this is what I have at the moment:

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear to me.

Comment: looks like it is not possible from interface builder alone because you wont be able to find out if the device has 3.5 inch screen or 4 inch screen so code is the way ahead.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran I've updated the question, hopefully its more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a `UIViewController` with a `TableView`, in it that you pin to the bottom of the `view` in interface builder. Then you add an `UIImageView` and you pin it to the top of the table and the top of the page. Given that it's static you don't even need to use the `UITableViewDelegate`.